# Android soft keyboard : hide then show immediately

Tags: android, show-hide, android-softkeyboard

Say i have an activity that shows fragment A. From fragment A i click a button to switch to fragment B. 
On Fragment A, i hide the soft keyboard in onPause() method.
On Fragment B, i show the soft keyboard in onResume() method.

Now when i click the button, fragment B is shown but the keyboard is not shown, which is not good. 
If fragment A doesn't use keyboard (remove the hide-soft-keyboard code in onPause()), then it works fine.

I set the breakpoint, and definitely fragment A's onPause is called before fragment B's onResume(). 
So in theory i think the keyboard should still be shown no matter what.

Any idea ?

Comment: What I suspect is happening is that the calls to hide and show the keyboard are being scheduled to run on the UI thread, with the show following almost immediately after the hide. Since the keyboard takes some time to animate off screen, I suspect the show command is dequeued from the UI handler and tries to execute, but finds the keyboard is still there, so does nothing.

Comment: That's what i suspect also. But doing a delay is not a clean way. I wonder if there's any better way.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't manipulate the keyboard in onPause() / onResume().

Comment: @Karakuri : can you elaborate more ?

Comment: I would remove keyboard manipulation. It certainly doesn't make sense that you will lower and re-raise the keyboard when switching from A to B.

Comment: @Karakuri : i want it to work in generic way without making any assumption. Screen A shows the keyboard, so when it's paused, it should dismiss the keyboard. It should not need to know if screen B will show the keyboard or not.

Comment: Screen A does not need to dismiss the keyboard in `onPause()`. If I press Home or switch apps, the keyboard usually goes away by itself. The only thing I would do, if anything at all, is raise the keyboard on screen B, but I'd still prefer it to be done based on a text field gaining focus. Sometimes it's better not to try and outsmart the system.

Comment: @Karakuri : it's not an option. If i don't dismiss the keyboard in onPause(), then when i switch from fragment A to some other fragment, the keyboard is still there, although there's no focused text field. And for fragment B, it's a message compose screen, so the text field is auto focus, but the keyboard is not shown unless you explicitly say so.

Answer (score 0):

You could delay the shown of the keyboard a little. something like:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        //show the keybpoard
    }

}, 500);
```